# Why append() runs after the function finishes in Python?

Tags: python, append

```py
a = [1,2,3]
b=[]
c=[]
def function1():
    b.append(a)
    c.append(a[:])
    a[0], a[1] = a[1], a[0]
function1()
print(b)
print(c)
```

```py
[[2, 1, 3]]
[[1, 2, 3]]
```

Why there is difference between list b and c? It means .append() runs after the order of list a is modified?

Comment: The contents of `b` are a reference to `a`, so when you change `a`, it changes the contents of `b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b.append(a)` adds the list in `a` to `b`. Now `a` and `b[0]` reference the same object. `a[0], a[1] = a[1], a[0]` affects that one single object as seen by both of these variables.

`a[:]` makes a copy of the list. So `c.append(a[:])` puts a unique copy of the list in `c`. `a` and `c[0]` are different objects. 
`a[0], a[1] = a[1], a[0]` does not affect the copied list in `c`.

Answer (score 0):

`a[:]` generates a new list. See the below snippet.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = a[:]
>>> a is b
False
```

So, when you are doing `b.append(a)` and `c.append(a[:])`, you are appending different lists to `b` and `c` respectively.
Modifying `a` doesn't affect `a[:]`